# Android Toolbar title is too low and get cropped

Tags: android, android-layout, android-toolbar

The default Support Toolbar shows the title too low and crops the bottom part of the TextView. The only solution not to get it cropped is to hide this Toolbar and replace it by a Toolbar Widget, added to the activity's xml, and set it as the support toolbar.
But even with this solution the title is at the same position (not vertically aligned with the back button). It's not cropped, but not good enough as this messed up alignment makes the toolbar look ugly.

I'm using the 25.1.0 support library and targeting API 24.
I don't use any custom toolbar style.

I set the title using `setTitle("My Title");` in `onCreate()`. Though I don't think it's related in any way with this function, as you can see on the following screenshot that even the Manifest's Activity Title shown in the preview is too low and cropped.

You can see on this screen shot the cropped title. Why is my title showing lower than it should?

[image: Preview of cropped title with the default Toolbar]

Comment: add the code where you set the title for more details

Comment: I simply call `setTitle(title);` in `onCreate()`

Comment: Please show your relevant code and XML

Comment: There is no XML, it's an empty activity.

Comment: Show your styles xml file. It looks you have some styles, which affected TextView in toolbar

Comment: Post the style or theme of your `Activity`.

Comment: Ah yes you were right, i had
`<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextView</item>` changing the padding of all TextView, including the one in the toolbar. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the fix thanks to Demand & Reaz,

My Activity theme was overriding the style of all TextView, including the one in the toolbar. This style had a bigger padding, messing up the title alignment.

I removed `<item name="android:textViewStyle">@style/TextView</item>` from it and applied this style to all the TextView individually.